# Is this extension of Goldbach's conjecture obviously false?

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

[Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) is:

> Every even integer greater than $2$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes.

Extension of Goldbach's conjecture is:

> Every number from $p\mathbb{Z}$ greater than $p$ can be expressed as the sum of $p$ primes

where $p\mathbb{Z}=\lbrace 0, \pm p, \pm 2p, \pm3p,\dots\rbrace$.

You can find a counterexamples?

For example if $p=5$:

- $10=2+2+2+2+2$
- $15=3+3+3+3+3$
- $20=2+3+3+5+7$
- ...
- $100=47+2+17+17+17$

Who can make this programming?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all we will assume that the Goldbach's conjecture is true, so given an integer  $n=kp$ with $k\geq 4$ ($k=3,2$ are easy), we will prove that $n$ is the sum of $p$ primes.

If $p=2,$ it's the Goldbach's conjecture and it's true, so we can assume that $p>2$.

**Case 1** If $n$ is even, let's write 
$$n=\underbrace{2+\cdots+2}_{p-2}+(n-2(p-2)),$$
and because $(n-2(p-2))=(k-2)p+4\geq4$ and it's even, then it can expressed as the sum of two primes. Hence, $n$ is the sum of $p$ primes.

**Case 2** If $n$ is odd, let's write 
$$n=3+\underbrace{2+\cdots+2}_{p-3}+(n-2(p-3)-3),$$
and because $(n-2(p-3)-3)=(k-2)p+3\geq4$ and it's even, then it can expressed as the sum of two primes. Hence, $n$ is the sum of $p$ primes.

So we proved the following statement:
$$\text{Goldbach's conjecture} \implies \text{Extension of Goldbach's conjecture}$$

But Goldbach's conjecture is a particular case of the extension of Goldbach's conjecture (when $p=2$), hence:
$$\text{Goldbach's conjecture} \iff \text{Extension of Goldbach's conjecture}$$

**Conclusion** The extension of Goldbach's conjecture as you define it is equivalent to the Goldbach's conjecture itself, and hence no one will ever find a counterexample or prove it unless (s)he solves Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: I think that this can be modified to : every integer larger than $2p$ is the sum of $p$ primes

Comment: Always it surprised me that nobody expressed  Goldbach's conjecture as follows: "Every integer >3 is equidistant from two primes". It appears to me so nice. (and the 3 could be incorporated with the convention of 1 be prime).

Comment: A remark: in order to prove this equivalence you don't need to assume Golbach's conjecture is true as you did. You have just a logic equivalence.

Comment: @Ataulfo I did not assume it for proving the equivalence, it's just the first thing to do in order to prove an implication, I assume Goldbach's conjecture is true and then I proved the other result. This is not general assumption in the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose Goldbach is true.  Let n be your candidate number.  Then either n is even or odd.  If even, then it is the sum of 2 primes.  If odd then n - 3 is even so n is the sum of 3 primes.  In no case would you need more than 3 primes.

Comment: You may not *need* more than 3 primes, but can you *use* $p$ primes?

Comment: Sure.  Inductively suppose you have settled the question for L - 1 and all numbers less than n.  Then just look at n - 2.